# ¿Porque se causa el problema al crear via Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Pregunta

Bueno estoy creando `Select` con opciones que vienen desde una base de datos las cuales se crean a partir de un `for` y a su vez se crea un botón, el que debiera insertar un `div` con cierto contenido, pero al momento de dar el evento que al hacer `click` se cree ese contenedor, nada ocurre.

Tampoco aparecen errores en el `debugger`, solo no ocurre nada y por el momento no logro encontrar el error, seria de mucha ayuda si alguien me guiara ya que hace poco tiempo estoy utilizando `Jquery`.

**A continuación dejare el contenido que se crea al ocurrir un change en el select:**

```
    $('#select_perfil').on('change', function select_perfil() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/select_perfil',
    data: $('#select_perfil').serialize(),
    success: function(json) {
      if (json.success == 1) {
        var mes = json.message;
        var but = $('<input type="button" id="boton_asignar" title="revisar" class="btn-success btn-md" value="Asignar Usuarios">');
        var inp = $('<input type="hidden" id="usuario">')
        $('#resultado option').remove();
        $('#boton_asignar').remove();
        $('#usuario').remove();
        $('#ejecutivos').append('<option>--</option>')
        for (var i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {
          $('#ejecutivos').append('<option class="opcion" value="' + mes[i][0] + '">' + mes[i][0] + '</option>');
        }
        $('#resultado').append(inp);
        $('#form_opciones').append(but);
        $('#ejecutivos').on('change', function() {
          $('#ejecutivos option:selected').each(function() {
            var str = "";
            str += $(this).text();
            $('#usuario').val(str);
          });
        })
      } else {
        $('#resultado option').remove();
        $('#boton_asignar').remove();
        $('#usuario').remove();
        $('#ejecutivos').append('<option>--</option>')
      }

    },
    error: function( /*xhr, status*/ ) {
      msg_box_alert(xhr.responsetext);
    }
  });
});
$('#select_perfil').one('click', function crear_select() {
  var sel = $('<select></select>');
  var lab = $('<label><strong>Asignar ejecutivos a Supervisor</strong></label><br>');
  $('#resultado').append(lab);
  $('#resultado').append(sel);
  sel.attr('id', 'ejecutivos');
  $('#ejecutivos').append('<option>--</option>')
});
```

[image: Lo que se crea en el change del primer select]

**Esto se crea de buena manera en cuanto produzco un cambio en el `select`.**

**Pero al intentar crear algo después de hacer `click` en el `botón` Asignar Usuario no ocurre nada, dejare a continuación el `código`:**

```
$('#boton_asignar').on('click',function(){
  var mostrarTodo = $('<section class="content"><!-- Default box --><div class="box" id="caja_secundaria"><!-- Custom Tabs (Pulled to the right) --><div class="nav-tabs-custom"><ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-rigth"><li class="active"><a href="#tab_2-2" data-toggle="tab"><label for="">Usuario</label></a></li><li class="pull-left header"></li></ul><div class="tab-content"><div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1-1"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label for="">Usuarios no asignados</label></div><div class="col-md-6"><label for="">Usuarios asignados</label></div></div></div><!-- /.tab-pane --></div></div></div></section>');
  $('#controlTotal').append(mostrarTodo);

});
```

**¨Gracias de antemano espero alguien pueda comprender el problema y ayudarme a solucionarlo**

**PD: `$('#controlTotal')` es un `div` que contiene 1 hijo que es el `select` con las opciones hasta el botón, la idea seria que el `append` fuera después de este.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta cambiando esto:

```
$('#boton_asignar').on('click',function(){
  var mostrarTodo = $('<section class="content"><!-- Default box --><div class="box" id="caja_secundaria"><!-- Custom Tabs (Pulled to the right) --><div class="nav-tabs-custom"><ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-rigth"><li class="active"><a href="#tab_2-2" data-toggle="tab"><label for="">Usuario</label></a></li><li class="pull-left header"></li></ul><div class="tab-content"><div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1-1"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label for="">Usuarios no asignados</label></div><div class="col-md-6"><label for="">Usuarios asignados</label></div></div></div><!-- /.tab-pane --></div></div></div></section>');
  $('#controlTotal').append(mostrarTodo);

});
```

Por esto:

```
$(document).on('click', '#boton_asignar',function(){
  var mostrarTodo = $('<section class="content"><!-- Default box --><div class="box" id="caja_secundaria"><!-- Custom Tabs (Pulled to the right) --><div class="nav-tabs-custom"><ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-rigth"><li class="active"><a href="#tab_2-2" data-toggle="tab"><label for="">Usuario</label></a></li><li class="pull-left header"></li></ul><div class="tab-content"><div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1-1"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label for="">Usuarios no asignados</label></div><div class="col-md-6"><label for="">Usuarios asignados</label></div></div></div><!-- /.tab-pane --></div></div></div></section>');
  $('#controlTotal').append(mostrarTodo);

});
```

Lo que pasa en tu código es que al momento de dar click nuevamente en el botón, como ya había sido eliminado anteriormente, no se reconoce y al cambiar a este selector lograrás que se reconozca en todo momento y así se pueda ejecutar la función.

Comment: gracias, me gustaría saber cual es la diferencia ya que no doy selección directa al botón, sino que da una vuelta.¿ cual es la diferencia técnica?
de todas maneras muchas gracias, solucionaste mi problema.

Comment: La diferencia es que en el segundo selector estás seleccionado siempre el documento como tal y estas haciendo una especie de find para que encuentre un elemento específico y le aplique el evento. Me alegra que te sirviera

Comment: es recomendable utilizar siempre una búsqueda de tipo $(document).on(... o es preferible seguir haciéndolo de manera directa?

Comment: @felipeandrade yo siempre uso el selector directo EXCEPTO en casos como el tuyo en el que tengo que crear elementos dinámicamente, en esos casos uso el selector que has aprendido hoy ! :D